Rust : Cast a Enum to itself with Generics Specialization
I'm using generics specialization to have custom compile time type on some enum data structure :
pub trait MyEnumState{}

// All state are Zero Sized Type
pub struct State1; impl MyEnumState for State1{};
pub struct State2; impl MyEnumState for State2{};

// Note : I don't know is there is a PhantomData<S> for an enum
pub enum MyEnum<S: MyEnumState> {
    A,
    B,
    C(i32), // Can also have some data
    // ... long enum
}

Now I would like to be able to cast them around : same value, different type
// How to avoid this mess ???
impl MyEnum<State1> {
    pub fn to_state2(self) -> MyEnum<State2> {
        match self {
            MyEnum::A => MyEnum::A,
            MyEnum::B => MyEnum::B,
            MyEnum::C(v) => MyEnum::C(v),
        }
    }
}

// I can proably make a generic function
// ```
// fn cast
//     <StateBegin : MyEnumState, StateEnd : MyEnumState>
// (val MyEnum<StateBegin>) -> MyEnum<StateEnd> { ... }
// ```
// to avoid repetition but I still have at least 1 giant match to implement
impl MyEnum<State2> { ... }



impl<S : MyEnumState> MyEnum<S> 
{
   pub fn to_state<NewState : MyEnumState>(self) ->  MyEnum<NewState> 
   {
      // how ?!
   }
}

This is just a simple example, the goal is to have 0 match statements to avoid matching for all existing enum variant.

How is for example State1 a state when it doesn't contain anything?

Because you can impl different function if you have a MyEnum<State1>, or MyEnum<State2>.
impl MyEnum<State1>{ fn foo(&self) {} }
impl MyEnum<State2>{ fn bar(&self) {} }
You can search for "rust state machine" on the web to see awesome use of Zero Sized Type :)

@trueequalsfalse it's called the typestate pattern and State1 by virtue of being a different type than State2 can enable different handling of MyEnum<State1> and MyEnum<State2> obviously it can only be used at compile time as after that type information is no longer available.

One way is to put the PhantomData field outside of the enum in a wrapper struct:
use core::marker::PhantomData;

pub enum MyEnum {
    A,
    B,
    C(i32),
}

pub struct EnumWithState<S: MyEnumState> {
    data: MyEnum,
    _state: PhantomData<S>,
}

Then you can implement the type casting function on EnumWithState:
impl<S: MyEnumState> EnumWithState<S> {
    fn to_state<S2: MyEnumState>(self) -> EnumWithState<S2> {
        EnumWithState {
            data: self.data,
            _state: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}

